# Как в cmd скрипте запустить сначала окружение, а потом сам скрипт(python)

Tags: python, cmd, bat, pycharm

Нужен батник который за раз зайдёт в окружение и запустит скрипт.

Вот так просто не получается:

```
@.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
@.\bot_main.py
@pause
```

Comment: `call` пробовали?

Comment: @ Stanislav Volodarskiy Пока нет. Сейчас прочитал про него, что то не очень пойму как это может пригодится.

Comment: Без `call` новый батник вытеснит старый из интерпретатора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в bot_main.py первой строчкой (для запуска через `py`(двойным кликом по файлу)):

```
#!полныйпуть\venv\bin\python.exe
```

или пропиши путь к site-packages в sys.path в самом скрипте

или пропиши переменные окружения PYTHONHOME

или просто копирни батник activate.bat и там в конце допиши старт скрипта - что, пожалуй, самый простой вариант.

Answer (score 3):

Прямой вызов бат-файла из бат-файла крадёт управление.

`set_z.bat`:

```
@echo off
echo in set_z.bat
set Z=1
```

`main.bat`:

```
@echo off
set Z=0
echo Z is %Z%
echo before set_z.bat
set_z.bat
echo after set_z.bat
echo Z is %Z%
```

Запускаем `main.bat` и управление не возвращается обратно в основной батник:

```
Z is 0
before set_z.bat
in set_z.bat
```

Если использовать `call` ...

```
@echo off
set Z=0
echo Z is %Z%
echo before set_z.bat
call set_z.bat
echo after set_z.bat
echo Z is %Z%
```

... то управление возвращается и окружение изменилось как нужно:

```
Z is 0
before set_z.bat
in set_z.bat
after set_z.bat
Z is 1
```

Для полноты картины третий вариант. Если нужно вызвать батник, но сохранить окружение, то `cmd /c ...`:

```
@echo off
set Z=0
echo Z is %Z%
echo before set_z.bat
cmd /c set_z.bat
echo after set_z.bat
echo Z is %Z%
```

Управление возвращается обратно, но окружение не тронуто:

```
Z is 0
before set_z.bat
in set_z.bat
after set_z.bat
Z is 0
```